# How To make webservice Response faster in Android Like I-Phone

Tags: android, performance, android-service, webservice-client

I am fetching data from web-service successfully. But the time taken is more, compared to same in I-Phone. I dont know exactly why.

**Is anyone have material to fetch data fast (like I-Phone) in android....**

My Code is:

```
HttpResponse res = null;
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeout1 = 1000*8;
        int timeout2 = 1000*8;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        //HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id", user_Id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kAreaNo",Chapter_Id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("QuestionCount",question_Count+""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StartingQno",start_From+""));

        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
        URL+=paramString;
        HttpGet post=new HttpGet(URL);

        try {

            res=httpClient.execute(post);
                            Log.i("Response=",res.getEntity().toString()+"Response aa");
            Log.i("Response=",res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"Response aa");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
            try{
            if (res.getEntity() != null) {
                   String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity()); 
        } catch(Exception e){
                    ......
                    }
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where you are spending your time.

Comment: Thanks...Ok, i will try by this. But i don't have used traceview ever.

Comment: Can you please tell me , Is there anything wrong with my code while making Http Call.

Comment: For all we know, the problem is not in the code you show above, but rather somewhere else. Use Traceview to determine precisely where you are spending your time.

Comment: Nothing that tells us why it would be slower than the equivalent iOS call. If its a large response then maybe adding a gzip header would help.

Comment: do we need to use gzip at the server side also or only at client side.

Comment: If you add an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header then the server will use gzip if it has the ability and it is enabled. Most modern web servers support gzip encoding. But I'd still profile your code before just trying random fixes.